# How do I create cubes on grid vertices with their size and vert count based on a noise map?

Tags: modeling, scripting, geometry-nodes, instances

I've tried to make this a bunch of different ways, but I end up with just cubes scaled on the grid.

I can subdivide a basic cube, but I really need regularity and the ability to increase cube size and vert count incrementally rather than doubling the resolution every step.

[image: Node definition with different elements]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution that you could use as a start.
[image]

The TWEAK input could probably be calculated with some maths based on grid size and VERT_COUNT.